# Recover element by which an rdd was grouped

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a code like so:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda userList: process_full(list(userList[1])))

def process_full(given_list):
    num_times = len(given_list)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(1,num_times):
        new_list.append((given_list[i][1] - given_list[i-1][1],
                         given_list[i][2] , given_list[i][3], **user_id**))
    return new_list
```

where rdd1 contains `user_id` as the key. Now, inside the `process_full` function, I am creating a list with many of the other elements in `rdd1` (from different columns). I would like to append the `user_id` by which I grouped, to that list created in `process_full`.

Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: Also `flatMapValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key by which you grouped the dataframe is in the `userList[0]` variable. You can simply add it as an input to the `process_full` method:

```
def process_full(key, given_list):
    // Same as before but add the key to new_list
```

and in the lambda function:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda userList: process_full(userList[0], list(userList[1])))
```